# Clear a html form when revisiting via history

Tags: php

I just implemented a sendmail in PHP called from a html page with a form. It requires filling some textfields, then pressing the submit button causing the mail to be sent. So far so good.

Now I need this form to be cleared on successful mail transmission.

My guess is that Internet Explorer (or other) saves all field values when moving on to another page. This makes it easy to go back in browser history and resend the mail. What I want is that on a succesful transmission of the mail the form cache (or whatever) is cleared. This must be done in the PHP page called.

Has anyone got a clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make the form page uncachable and the client will request it every time.

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is being able to read the form by using the back button:

```
window.onunload=function(){for(var i=0;i<document.forms.length;i++){document.forms[i].reset()}}
```

This assumes that using the form will not unload/leave the page.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are talking about?

[SO393882 - Cross-browser techniques for disabling password caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393882/cross-browser-techniques-for-disabling-password-caching)

Although they talk about username/password stuff mostly, i think any of those techniques could prevent what you need to prevent for your form.  Particularly the solutions that involves hashing/altering the input field's names, and simply `autocomplete=off` in your `<input>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could submit the form via AJAX and on success send back Javascript which clears all form fields.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check with your users if they really want their painstakingly entered data to disappear. Especially if they expect their back buttons to take them back to a step in the process where they need to correct an error (e.g. wrong email address).