# can we avoid browser's "remember password" when a user tries to log in to the system?

Tags: php, browser, passwords, header

I know that this feature is to enhance user experience (by not retyping their details every time) and users can tweak their browser settings, but is it possible to send some "headers" etc (or any method, I mean server side controlling) so that when users try to log into my site they dont get this "Do you want IE/Firefox to remember your password?" prompt?

I am not very sure if it is possible? what would you say? Any ideas will help.

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393882/cross-browser-techniques-for-disabling-password-caching

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put 'autocomplete="off"' in the input tag of the field. This works in IE and Firefox, but it's not part of the HTML standard, so you'll end up with invalid mark-up.

Comment: Very few people care about Valid markup. I find it funny when they put buttons on their site to show that its valid and they rarely are valid.

Answer (score 8):

Add autocomplete="off" to the <form>

[Mozilla docs on autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)

Answer (score 1):

Besides using the autocomplete attribute you could add a random number to the url that receives the posted form.Each time the form is presented to the user it will be different so the browser's attempt to recall will fail.