# Firefox stored userid and password showing up in my form

Tags: html, forms, firefox, passwords, caching

I am building a form for changing a users password in the database.  Typical: Ask for the current password, a new password and to re-type the new password.

My problem is that the cached userid and password for the website are showing up in the current password field (userid shows up) and the new password field (current password shows up).  Of course if I clear all credentials from FF's cache it doesn't show up.  My question is why is it showing up here.  I have changed the names of the field and the value field is empty.  I don't understand where it is coming from.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  BTW it doesn't appear to happen in IE or Chrome browsers...

Below is my code:

```
        <li id="li_1" >
    <label class="description" for="element_1">Current Password </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_1" name="old_pass" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_1"><small>Enter your current password</small></p> 
    </li>       <li class="section_break">

    </li>       <li id="li_3" >
    <label class="description" for="element_3">New Password </label>
    <div>
        **<input id="element_3" name="new_pass" class="element text medium" type="password" maxlength="255" value=""/>** 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_3"><small>Enter your new Password</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_4" >
    <label class="description" for="element_4">Confirm New Password </label>
    <div>
        **<input id="element_4" name="new_pass2" class="element text medium" type="password" maxlength="255" value=""/>** 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_4"><small>Re-type your new password</small></p> 
    </li>

                <li class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="230071" />

            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: old_pass *isn't* a password field?

Comment: Anyway, see [Cross-browser techniques for disabling password caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393882/cross-browser-techniques-for-disabling-password-caching) which uses "autocomplete" attribute. Not sure if it's HTML4/5 compliant, but post claims it works on modern browsers.

Comment: OK upon further research I have found a solution.  Add autocomple="off" for the input field.  I am very happy with this.  However, I still don't understand why this is happening...  The name and id's of the input fields are completely different. The value fields on the input fields are blank.  I just don't get how autocomplete works I guess.  Can someone please enlighten me??

Comment: I understand how to disable password caching on ff but what if one of my users has it enabled???

Answer (score 1):

As you found out you can use...

```
autocomplete="off"
```

... to turn off that annoying auto-complete :)

I'm no expert but I guess the secret of auto-complete is to map user input with field names/ids/types etc. But that could be all wrong, I don't know, but it sounds plausible.