# How does wellsfargo.com prevent the web browser from asking to save the username / password?

Tags: html, passwords

This has baffled me for years! (Although I never took the time to find out how they do this)

Basically you have to enter your username and password every single time you log in to their online banking.

No browser ever asks to save the password for you

Comment: Duplicate: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality) & [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393882/cross-browser-techniques-for-disabling-password-caching)

Comment: I wrote a chrome extension to fix this. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wells-fargo-remember-user/cgadmadfnbdaplnanejoebmbfpgpliee

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because the have `autocomplete="off"` in their form